# Failing to tweak runtime options for Tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, java, tomcat

(I tried Google first and got a million articles which were simply rehashes of the installation readme from tomcat).

I am trying to change the Java command line used for running Tomcat9 on Ubuntu 20.04. Specifically, I'm trying to set Xmx, enable gc logging, define a HTTP proxy and some other stuff. Tomcat is installed from repo. I read somewhere (didn't make a note of the URL at the time) that this should be done by adding an override to the unit file and setting the required arguments in the JAVA_OPTS variable. So I did this....

```
[Service]

ProtectSystem=full

Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-noverify -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -server -Dprod=true 
-Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat9/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.bip -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.bip 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -javaagent:/var/lib/tomcat9/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar 
-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
```

(I've added in some line breaks in the Environment line to aid readability here - in the source file its a single line).

Just to be sure, I also ran a `systemctl daemon reload` but when I stop/start the service, I see this.....

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 
-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 
-Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat9 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

These are not my JAVA_OPTs.

Checking through the startup chain (see below) I can't see anything which would remove the options I had set.

```
/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service
    /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh
        $CATALINA_BASE/policy/catalina.policy
    /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh
        /etc/default/tomcat9
        /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-locate-java.sh
        $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh
```

I would rather keep my config separate from the packaged software. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had misread one of the files. /etc/default/tomcat9 OVERRIDES the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.

From the comments in this file, it appears to be the place the packager expects users to place their own options in.